# Swift hidden UIView displays on segue

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am struggling with this small issue of mine, where I am currently using ChainableAnimations to create a sliding menu. When I click the menu button, the menu toggles perfectly. However, when I click another button from the menu, the sliding menu slides back and does a segue - but suddenly the menu appears for half a second before the segue. This is my code:

```
@IBAction func socialMediaButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sideview.animator.move(x: -320).easeInOutSine.animate(t: 1.0) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoSocialMedia", sender: self)

        }
        collapseButton.animator.rotate(angle: -90).easeInOutSine.animate(t: 0.5)
```

I have also tried to work around this by adding this with no luck:

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        sideview.alpha = 0
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        sideview.alpha = 0
    }
```

Could someone please help me with this? Much appreciated.

Comment: You can make use of `View Debugger` from `XCode`

Comment: @NileshPol Not to sound rude at all, but how exactly would that help me?